# Determine the convergence radius for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)^kx^n}{(kn)!}, \quad k\in\mathbb{N}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

The ratio test gives $$|x|\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{((n+1)!)^k\cdot(kn)!}{(k(n+1))!\cdot(n!)^k}\right|=|x|\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|(n+1)^k\cdot\frac{(kn)!}{(k(n+1))!}\right|.$$

I'm having trouble simplifying $\frac{(kn)!}{(k(n+1))!}$, so far I have:

$$\frac{(kn)!}{(k(n+1))!}=\frac{kn(kn-1)...}{(kn+k)(kn+k-1)...(kn)(kn-1)...}=\frac{1}{(kn+k)(kn+k-1)...(kn+1)}.$$

This means that I have $$|x|\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)^k}{(kn+k)(kn+k-1)...(kn+1)},$$

since the highest power after expansion of the denominator and numerator are $1$ and $k^k$ respectively, the above is asymptotically equal to

$$|x|\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)^k}{(kn+k)(kn+k-1)...(kn+1)}\sim|x|\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^k+\text{lesser powers}}{k^kn^k+\text{lesser powers}}=|x|\frac{1}{k^k},$$

thus the radius is $R=k^k$.

I feel really insecure here using these vauge arguments. Is it mathematically correct to reason like this?

Comment: I think this is fine. If you want to be more precise, you can write $o(n^k)$ instead of "lesser powers".

Comment: Okay, so $o$ is for lesser powers and $O$ is for greater powers?